# Quitar el dominio al equipo

Tags: windows

Tengo un equipo con Windows 8.1, que alguna vez fué parte de un dominio, mas que nada para tener ciertas carpetas compartidas; pero hace como 2 años que ya no, durante ese tiempo he seguido usando el equipo con mi cuenta de usuario. El problema es que he estado teniendo ciertos errores sin mensaje alguno, y al ver el Visor de Eventos, solo veo cosas relacionadas a que no encuentra el dominio.
Mi cuenta de usuario es de tipo Administrador. Además acabo de habilitar la cuenta Administrador.

Mi pregunta es, si quito el dominio del equipo, ¿podré seguir entrando con mi cuenta de usuario? ¿Qué implicancias podría tener el quitar el dominio, si solo lo ocupo localmente?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es una pregunta de administración de sistemas, no de programación.

Comment: Entras con tu cuenta local que has creado antes de acceder al dominio. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para sacar el equipo del dominio Equipo -> Propiedades -> Cambiar configuración En la pestaña "Nombre de Equipo" tienes una opción para cambiar. Necesitarás permisos de Administrador del Dominio.

Antes de nada ten en cuenta que las cuentas del dominio (DOMINIO\NombreDeUsuario o NombreDeUsuario@DOMINIO será eliminadas del equipo

Puedes crear cuentas denominadas "locales" que seguirán existiendo en el equipo pese a sacarlo del Dominio.

Como observación te diría que sacar un equipo de un dominio puede estar bloqueado por las políticas de seguridad. En ese caso, solo queda hacer un copia de lo importante, formatear y restaurar las carpetas.

Comment: Precisamente mi cuenta es local.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si la cuenta es local no deberías tener ningún tipo de problema para sacarle del sominio, siempre y cuando tengas acceso a una cuenta que tenga privilegios de adminsitrador del Dominio